# Segmentation fault while writing back from a file into a struct, that is also a linked list

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have two structs in C. One is called full_file, and the other is called data_holder. full_file contains a pointer to data_holder, and data_holder contains a pointer to itself. I use this to make a linked list of numbers.

```
struct full_file {
    int magic_number;
    struct data_holder *number_list;
};

struct data_holder {
    unsigned long int number;
    struct data_holder *next;
};
```

My problem is that once I have the linked list, and full_file.number_list points to its first element, I save full_file into a file using fwrite().

```
int write_size = fwrite((char *)&numbers,1,sizeof(struct full_file),out_file);
if (write_size != sizeof(struct full_file)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: failure to write data into '%s'.\n",out);
    exit(8);
}
```

This doesn't seem to cause any problems. However, when I try to read these file contents into full_file again:

```
struct full_file numbers; 
int read_size = fread((char *)&numbers,1,sizeof(struct full_file),in_file);
```

There is a segmentation fault. I tried changing sizeof(struct full_file) to 0, and this segmentation fault doesn't happen. Of course that'd mean that no data would be retrieved from the file. I don't know what's wrong here. What can I do to solve this error and read get the linked list back?

Comment: You cannot read a pointer - those are transitory

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know what's wrong here.

```
struct full_file numbers; 
int read_size = fread((char *)&numbers,1,sizeof(struct full_file),in_file);
```

About the only way the `fread` could produce segmentation fault is if `in_file` is uninitialized, refers to `fclose`d file pointer, or is `NULL`.

Make sure to check `fopen` return (which is presumably what you used to initialize `in_file`) for errors.

Other random notes:

- you have `size` and `nmemb` parameters to `fread` reversed (not that it matters much),
- you should store result of `fread` in a `size_t` variable, not an `int` (it doesn't matter here either, but it's a good habit).
- storing pointers in a file on disk (as your `fwrite` does) it generally a very bad idea: you can't use them for anything when you read them back in a different program, or a different run of the same program.

Comment: Your last sentence is the relevant one.

Comment: What you said in your last sentence is most likely the problem. Does this mean that I cannot save linked lists into files?